# Perl - Parse last occurrence of whitespace

Tags: regex, perl, whitespace, filenames

I am trying to parse the last chunk of the following line:

```
77      0       wl1271/wpa_supplicant_lib/driver_ti.h
```

Unfortunately, the spaces are not always the same length. I assume that printf or something similar was used to output the data so it lined up in columns. This means that sometimes I have spaces, and sometimes I have tab characters.

I have successfully gotten the first two numbers through the use of regex in perl. The way I thought I would get the last bit would be to search of the last occurrence of any whitespace character and then grab the rest of the string starting there. I tried using `rindex` but that only accepts a character for the searchable parameter and not a regex (I thought that `\s` would do the trick).

Can anyone solve the issue I'm having here either by walking my through how to get the last whitespace character or by helping me with a solution to grab that string some other way?

Comment: maybe just remove last whitespace? (or whitespaces)? for what reason you care about them? `s/\s+$//; # farewell, whitespace`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not `split`?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = '77      0       wl1271/wpa_supplicant_lib/driver_ti.h';
my ( $num1, $num2, $lastPart ) = split ' ', $string;

print "$num1\n$num2\n$lastPart";
```

Output:

```
77
0
wl1271/wpa_supplicant_lib/driver_ti.h
```

Comment: Because it's not always spaces. Sometimes it uses tabs of different length and whatnot. There are more lines in the file than what are seen pasted here.

Comment: @user1897691 - `split ' '` splits on whitespace, including tabs.  It would work well for this.

Comment: Really? I was not aware of this. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1897691 - Indeed!  It's really made for this.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just match the regex `\S+$` - namely, the last set of non-whitespace characters in the string?

- `\S` = non-whitespace character
- `$` = end of line

Edit: You really should use `split` though, as suggested by Kenosis.

Comment: If there might be trailing whitespace as well, you can use `\S+\s*$`.

Comment: I notice you are using `$` which denotes the end of the string. If it wasn't clear, please let me know, but I was looking for the whitespace after the 0 but before `wl1271/wpa_supplicant_lib/driver_ti.h`. The filename is the string I'm trying to parse out.    EDIT: OH! You're using `\S` (capital). I did not notice. Thank you :D

Comment: I might be being really dumb right now but I did the following and got "1" every time... `my ($filename) = $_ =~ m/\S+\s*$/;`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in Perl, `m//` typically just acts as a boolean. The value of the last match is in `$&`.

(Also, just a stylistic comment: by default, patterns are matched on `$_`, and the `m` is also implied, so the line `$_ =~ m/\S+\s*$/;` is equivalent to the line `/\S+\s*$/;`.)

Comment: `$` is not end of string. `\z` is end of string.